# Use vector or map for input of a class of students?

Tags: c++, class, stdvector, stdmap

I am writing a code for storing information from user input, with two different strings and one char. The program is supposed to take in inputs about students until the user gives `stop` as a course name, and then Ask for a new student. All of the objects are printed out with an iterator `for` loop when the student name given is `stop`.

At the start, I created a class like this:

```
class Student{
public:
  string Name;
  string Course;
  char Grade;
};
```

Can a `vector` be used for all of the input?

I have tried using a `map`, but I am uncertain of the use.

Comment: C++ is case sensitive.  There is no `Class` in C++, the same thing with `String`, `Public` and `Char`.  By not using the proper casing, the code looks like it belongs to another computer language.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a list-of-students, use a data structure suitable for a list-of-students. A vector is one, and generally the one you should reach for if you don't have good reasons not to. You mention a map -- that associates a *key* with a *value*, so it's useful when you have a "key" that you might want to look up later. Which is right for you -- or for your problem -- depends on what you actually want to do with the data.

You might do something like this (not complete code: you would need to fill in the includes and supporting functions):

```
std::vector<Student> all_students;
while(true) {
  Student one_student;
  // Function reads from an input stream, puts information in Student&
  readStudentInformation(std::cin, one_student);
  if (reasonToStop(one_student)) { break; }
  else { all_students.append(one_student); }
}
```

You read things one at a time, and add the valid ones into the vector-of-students. (This sample code assumes you can look up how to use a `Student&`, a reference-to-student, to update the `one_student`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `vector`, `map` or any other container to store the student information. You choose one depending on WHAT you are going to do with it? Specifically - HOW will you access that information?

Also, your description hints that one student may take multiple courses, each with its own grade. You `class Student` can't store that.